# Detect if open dropdown menu is in viewport and react if it is not

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I´m trying to detect if a open dropdown menu is in the users viewport or if it is out of his view. I am using the `getBoundingClientRect()` method to compare the Rect cords to the viewports but it reacts kind of strange.
If the menu is fully visible, the dropdown should open to the bottom, if it isn't visible it should open to the top. For simplicity in my example it only logs the direction to the console.
Here is an example with the dropdown selector on the bottom of the page. If you open it, it will be too large for the viewport and a scrollbar appears. The function should detect, that the dropdown menu with the options isn't in the viewport anymore and should log `open to top`but it doesn't.

Please find the example at [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2Xrb6fGjzJXz46j1trfC?p=preview).

**So how can I detect if my dropdown menu is in the viewport to decide whether to open it to the top or the bottom?**

I prefer not to use jQuery to solve this issue, only if it´s inevitable!

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that when your `dropdown-menu` doesn't have `.shown` class it is has `display: none` style. With this style function `getBoundingClientRect()` returns something like `{top: 0, left: 0, width: 0, height: 0}`.
If your click to open menu your change `isMenuOpen` to `true` but Angular need some time to react on that action and add `class`.
So, the solution is to wrap all your code after `this.isMenuOpen = !this.isMenuOpen;` to the `setTimeout`.

Comment: Can you please provide me some sample code to show me your idea? That would be great!